# Add a class via for-loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, addclass

I have a very simple for-loop in jQuery:

```
var iEra;
for(iEra = 1; iEra <= li.length; iEra++) {
    li.addClass(iEra);
}
```

**li** is a variable targeting $('ul.class li') objects. **iEra** is the counter variable that should start from 1 up to the number of **li** objects present.

The main issue is that the function addClass is not happening at all. However if I replace it by, for example, **alert(iEra);**, I will get my 1-x alerts.

I know I could modify my for-loop to be a "constructor", like so:

```
var iEra;
for(iEra = 1; iEra <= li.length; iEra++) {
    parentOfli.append('<li class=" + iEra + "></li>');
}
```

That way I would get my classes 1-x added just fine. Problem is, those li objects are already being generated somewhere else.

I hope I explained myself thoroughly; if not, please let me know so!
Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/c3cXB/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class names **cannot** be a number.

Here is one that works: http://jsfiddle.net/c3cXB/10/

```
var li = $('ul.portfolio-excerpt').find('li');

var iEra, thumbLi = $('.thumbs ul li');
for (iEra = 1; iEra <= li.length; iEra++) {
    thumbLi.eq(iEra).addClass('class'+iEra);
}
```

Comment: Oh man, I'm so dumb. I actually though you could add numeric classes because it worked when appending the whole element. Thanks!

Comment: Class names can be numbers.

Comment: Uhhh... Not so sure about that one @Pointy -- as if you check the `classList` of any dom element they are always strings.

Comment: @Naftali they can be strings of numbers, like `"12345"`

Comment: ok? that is still a string in js

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a loop

```
$('.thumbs ul li').each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass(iEra);
}
```

Or this way, if you just want to add a class to all of the Li

```
$('.thumbs ul li').addClass(iEra);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's wrong with your example, I had to change css to 'li.thumbs' to see the following is working:

```
var $thumbLi = $('.thumbs ul li')
$('ul.portfolio-excerpt li:lt(' + $thumbLi.length + ')').addClass('thumbs');
```

See also http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/