# forloop div event listeners not adding/removing classes

Tags: javascript

```
if (div.id === 'firstDiv')
            {
                div.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        div.classList.remove('w-1/4')
                        div.classList.add('w-full')
                })
            }
```

I have this code block in a for loop, it checks the id of each div in the loop, and adds an event listener to it. However, while the event listener works if I `console.log` it, it doesn't actually do anything with the classList

Comment: I think it won't have access to the div variable

Comment: I forget what property of the event object gives you the element that the event listener is on etc. but you can console log it and check

Comment: What exactly does the loop look like? Depending on where/how `div` is declared, the way you set up the event handlers could fail.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7260548/14346235 do this helpful ?

Comment: @dineshoz that linked answer is wrong, and also that has nothing to do with the problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of div is unique to every div so it just work in one div and you didn't defined which div should be change in the classlist so specify it with "this" keyword